# Unknown interaction error from Collectors, discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

If the code is sent **twice or more in a row in same channel**, when I click on one of the Select menus, it gives the following error:
`DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction`

Where is the problem and how can I solve this problem?
This error is sent only when I send several messages in a row with active Collectors and then click on one of them.

<sub>Code:
code explanation: This code allows changing the role register in the db, user can first select the role he wants to change from the Select menus, then send the ID of new role</sub>

```js
module.exports = {
    async execute(interaction, db) {
        const { EmbedBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, StringSelectMenuBuilder, ComponentType } = require("discord.js");

        console.log(`${interaction.user.id} in ${interaction.guild.name} triggered ${__filename.split('/').pop()} command.`);

        await interaction.deferReply();

        const biographyRoles = {
            she: await db.get(`biography_roles_${interaction.guild.id}_she`),
            he: await db.get(`biography_roles_${interaction.guild.id}_he`),
            they: await db.get(`biography_roles_${interaction.guild.id}_they`),
            pronouns: await db.get(`biography_roles_${interaction.guild.id}_pronouns`),
        };

        const options = [
            {
                label: 'She/Her',
                value: 'she',
            },
            {
                label: 'He/Him',
                value: 'he',
            },
            {
                label: 'They/Them',
                value: 'they',
            },
            {
                label: 'Ask for pronouns',
                value: 'pronouns',
            }
        ];

        const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('color-role-select-menu')
                    .setPlaceholder('Select your Color role')
                    .addOptions(options)
            );

        const config = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor('#2f3136')
            .setAuthor({ name: `Biography roles Setup:`, iconURL: interaction.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }) || '' })
            .setFooter({ text: `Requested by ${interaction.user.username}`, iconURL: interaction.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }) || null })
            .setTimestamp()
            .setDescription(`Please select one of the following gender names to set up\n\n**Existing Biography Roles:**\nShe/Her: ${getRoleMention(biographyRoles.she)}\nHe/Him: ${getRoleMention(biographyRoles.he)}\nThey/Them: ${getRoleMention(biographyRoles.they)}\nAsk for pronouns: ${getRoleMention(biographyRoles.pronouns)}`);


        await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [config], components: [row] });

        const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({
            componentType: ComponentType.StringSelect,
            time: 60000,
            max: 1
        });

        collector.on("collect", async (i) => {
            if (i.user.id !== interaction.user.id) {
                i.reply({ content: `These menus aren't for you!`, ephemeral: true });
                return;
            }

            const roleKey = i.values[0];
            const roleName = options.find(option => option.value === roleKey).label;
            const roleDescription = `Please send a **${roleName}** role ID or mention it below\n`;

            i.update({ embeds: [config.setDescription(roleDescription)], components: [] });

            const collectormenssage = interaction.channel.createMessageCollector({
                time: 30000,
                max: 1,
            });

            collectormenssage.on("collect", async (m) => {
                const role = m.mentions.roles.first() || m.guild.roles.cache.get(m.content);

                if (!role || !role.id || !m.guild.roles.cache.has(role.id)) {
                    await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [config.setDescription('> Unable to find role, please check the provided role or ID\n')] });
                    return;
                }

                await db.set(`biography_roles_${interaction.guild.id}_${roleKey}`, role.id);
                await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [config.setDescription(`**${role} was added as ${roleName}** role, you can change it again with the same code\n`)] });
            });
        });

        setTimeout(function () {
            interaction.editReply({ components: [] });
        }, 60000);
    }
};

function getRoleMention(roleId) {
    return roleId ? `<@&${roleId}>` : `Not selected`;
}
```